# Obtener id en un datatable responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, datatable

Intento obtener el id en un datatable responsive, hasta ahora lo he podido hacer, pero cuando la tabla no es responsiva, de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnEliminarUsuario", function () {
  var idUsu = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
  console.log("idUsu", idUsu);
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema esta en que cuando se vuelve responsiva la tabla los botones quedan en otro tr, de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y entonces no puedo obtener el id que necesito. Estoy intentando con esto para ver si estoy en un tr hijo pero sin exito:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnEliminarUsuario", function () {
if((this).child.isShown()){
    var idUsu = $(this).parents("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
} else {
    var idUsu = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text();
}
console.log("idUsu", idUsu);
});
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el id que necesito?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnEliminarUsuario", function () {
if($(this).parents("tr").hasClass('child')){ //vemos si el actual row es child row
    var idUsu = $(this).parents("tr").prev().find('td:eq(0)').text(); //si es asi, nos regresamos al row anterior, es decir, al padre y obtenemos el id
} else {
    var idUsu = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text(); //si no lo es, seguimos capturando el id del actual row
}
console.log("idUsu", idUsu);
});
```

La comparto para quien esté en una situación similar, en español hay pocas páginas con información.